# Unexpected "Cannot access a disposed object" in clean up method

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, objectdisposedexception

I am facing a puzzling disposed object issue when I shut down my WPF application. If you spot any mistakes in my logic please point them out.

I have a `ColorManager` class with `update()` method, as shown below.

```
public void Update(ColorImageFrame frame)
{
    byte[] pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];

    frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);

    if (Bitmap == null)
    {
        Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frame.Width,
                                     frame.Height,
                                     96,
                                     96,
                                     PixelFormats.Bgr32,
                                     null);
    }
    // draw bitmap

    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Bitmap);   
}
```

I run this method in a separate thread. In my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I have the following:

```
    private void Initialise()
    {
        if (kinectSensor == null)
            return;
        // start kinect sensor        
        kinectSensor.Start();

        updateColourStreamThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(colorStreamDisplay));
        updateColourStreamThread.Name = "updateColourStreamThread";
        updateColourStreamThread.Start();

        // ...some more codes
     }

        void colorStreamDisplay()
        {
            while(isDisplayActive)
            {
                using (var frame = kinectSensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(500))
                {
                    if (frame == null) continue;

                    if (displayDepthStream) continue;

                    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => colorManager.Update(frame)));
                }
            }
        }
```

I have the following method in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to do the clean up after clicking the close button.

```
    private void Clean()
    {
        isDisplayActive = false;
        // some other codes

        if (kinectSensor != null)
        {
            updateColourStreamThread.Abort();
            updateDepthStreamThread.Abort();
            updateSkeletonStreamThread.Abort();

            kinectSensor.Stop();
            kinectSensor = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Closed successfully");
        }
```

My application throws "cannot access a disposed object" on `frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);` after I click the close button.

I switch the bool value to false to stop the loop, then I abort the thread, and stop the kinect device.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set your boolean to false, the application will exit the while loop:

1) Setting your `bool` to false

```
        isDisplayActive = false;
```

2) will exit this loop:

```
        while(isDisplayActive)
        {
            using (var frame = kinectSensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(500))
            {
                if (frame == null) continue;
                if (displayDepthStream) continue;

                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => colorManager.Update(frame)));
            }
        }
```

3) So your frame will go out of scope too. Consequently it will be disposed...

```
using (var frame = kinectSensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(500))
```

4) While your main thread did not yet execute the `Thread.Abort` yet.

5) And thus, your `CopyPixelDataTo` will be executed on an already disposed `frame` object.

```
frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
```

6) And kaboom, you have your object disposed exception.

---

### Thread.Abort is a bad idea.

You never know *how far* the executing thread was before it got executed, which can lead to all kinds of nasty side effects. Read more in this Q&A: [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)

What I would do in your situation is replace the

```
while(isDisplayActive)
```

with something like

```
while(colorThingyThreadIsBusy)
```

And set the `colorThingyThreadBusy` bool to false when your `Thread` is ready (=done processing).

In order to gracefully close your application I'd implement a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) instead of aborting Threads.

Comment: Ah! I didn't think of step 4! You're right. _You never know how far the executing thread was before it got executed_